# Formulário de comentário do facebook substitui o formulário do wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

Quero colocar duas plataformas de comentário no meu blog, o facebook e o próprio formulário do wordpress, mas quando eu coloco o código:

```
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

O formulário do é substituído pelo formulário do facebook sozinho e acaba ficando com dois formulários do facebook.

Mesmo quando eu tiro o do facebook e deixo só o código, o facebook ainda substitui sozinho.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Agradeço desde já!

**Lista de Plugins instalados:**

- Akismet
- All In One WP Security
- Facebook Comments Notifier
- Formulário de contato 7
- Jetpack por Wordpress.com
- Really Simple CAPTCHA
- WP Advanced Comment
- WP Missed Schedule
- WP-PageNavi
- Yoast SEO

Uso o **Facebook Comments Notifier** para receber uma notificação no facebook quando receber um comentário.

Estava tentando utilizar o **WP Advanced Comment** e funcionou, mas fica dando erro e não tem como responder um comentário, então estou tentando usar o do WP mesmo. Se tiver algum plugin bom e fácil de usar, é bem-vindo.

Comment: Provavelmente você tem um plugin instalado que está dando hook na função e inserindo o sistema de comentários do Facebook, desative todos os plugins e teste ou poste a lista dos plugins que você usa. Sem mais detalhes é difícil responder.

Comment: @RenanCavalieri Fiz o que você pediu, essa é a lista de todos os plugins que eu uso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você possui o plugin **[Facebook Comments Notifier](https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-comments-notifier/)** instalado, aqui está a descrição dele:

> The Facebook Comments Notifier plugin **adds the facebook comment system
>   in place of the default WordPress** comments and creates email
>   notifications on successfully posted comments.

Traduzindo, ele adiciona o sistema de comentários do Facebook no lugar do Wordpress.

Desinstale esse plugin e seu problema estará resolvido.

Recomendo que faça a implementação do sistema de comentários manualmente no seu template, você pode usar o gerador de códigos aqui.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Comment: Na verdade, eu uso esse plugin para receber as notificações de quando é feito um comentário, sem ele eu não tenho como eu saber se houve um novo comentário em um post, entende? Com ele aparece uma notificação no facebook. Conhece algum jeito de aparecer, pelo menos, uma notificação direto no wordpress, como se fosse um comentário direto nele? Assim eu não ia precisar mais desse plugin.

Comment: Se for para isso, não precisa desse plugin, você consegue receber as notificações de novos comentários definindo um moderador no seu sistema de comentários que pode ser gerado na página do link. Dê uma olhada aqui https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments - Porém, essa notificação vai aparecer no seu perfil associado à moderação, e não no site. Talvez haja algum plugin pra isso que não crie esse vinculo pra associar o comentários padrão com o Facebook.

Comment: Funcionou =) Obrigada! Agora só falta eu fazer um formulário manual.